# angularjs multiple instances of the same service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I want more than one instance of a user service (selectedUser & currentUser), they provide the same functionality. Currently I just get around the problem by creating two services that pull their definition from a local function:

```
angular.module('myUserModule', [])

.factory('userFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
  return function getUser(userId) {
    return new $q(function (resolve) {
      //Gets the user with the provided userId
    }
  }
}])

.value('currentUserId', '')
.value('selectedUserId', '')

.service('currentUserService', ['userFactory', 'currentUserId', User])
.service('selectedUserService', ['userFactory', 'selectedUserId', User]);

function User(userFactory, userId) {
  var self = this;
  var promise = userFactory(userId);
  promise.then(function setUserSuccess(result) {
    self.user = result;
  }
}
```

Just wondering how other people have approached this problem.

Updated:
Just to clarify that I am making use of these services as singletons too.

Comment: Seems like all you need is one user service that returns an object containing multiple methods. Only returning one method per service is very limiting

Comment: it does seem somewhat overkill to me, but what do you mean by limiting?

Comment: Forgot to mention it's the cut down version, it's not just one method

Answer (score 1):

In an unrelated question the solution ended up using a factory that creates multiple instances:

[what is the scope of a service in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881084/what-is-the-scope-of-a-service-in-angularjs/31881191#31881191)

Use the Factory Pattern.

In essence, if you have a User service, you can use a factory to return a unique instance of the service.

```
function User(userId, $http) {

    var self = this;    

    $http.get('/api/user/', {userId: userId}).success(function(result) {

        self.details = result.data;
    }):
}

userFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
function userFactory($http) {

    return function(user) {

        return new User(user, $http);
    } 
}
angular.module('app').factory('user', userFactory);
```

But for this example, you can just use `$resource`. This is a built in angular factory that returns unique Resource instances.

Comment: Must admit I haven't used $resource so far, will look into

Comment: This is a great method, and I have used this. Thank you for the idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use use your factory as an API to return a collection of objects with getter and setter methods.

You can declare new Factory by using the `new` keywords. However, it is preferable to encapsulate the creation of an instance into a getter method.

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function userFactory($http, $q){

    //Create our userFactory
    function userFactory(num){
      this.num = num;
    };

    //Retrieve some user data for example
    function getUser(id){
      return new $q(function(resolve){
        resolve({id: id, data: [1,2,3,4]});
      });
    }

    //Another method
    function awesome(){
      console.log('Awesome method called by : ' + this.num);
    }

    //Set method by prototyping
    userFactory.prototype.getUser = getUser;
    userFactory.prototype.awesome = awesome;

    return {
      //Use get method to return a new instance of our factory
      get: function(){
        //Pass a random id for our factory
        return new userFactory(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100));
      }
    }

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('UserFactory', userFactory);

})();
```

The you can create your own instance by using the **.get()** method :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, UserFactory) {


  var factoryA = UserFactory.get()
  var factoryB = UserFactory.get();

  console.log('A num instance ' + factoryA.num);
  console.log('B num instance ' + factoryB.num);

  factoryA.getUser(1).then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });

  factoryB.awesome();

  console.log('Equality = ' + angular.equals(factoryA, factoryB));

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();


(function(){

function Controller2($scope, UserFactory) {

  var factoryC = UserFactory.get()

  console.log('C num instance ' + factoryC.num);

}

angular
.module('app')
.controller('ctrl2', Controller2);

})();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem ideal from an injectability perspective, what if I want this instance in some other controller or service? Unless I've missed something?

Comment: If you want multiple instance in multiple controller, just pass your `UserFactory` in your controller parameter, and then create an instance just by `UserFactory.get()`. No need to use `new` keyword. You have a safe and proper way to handle multiple service. Do you get it ?

Comment: I mean rather won't it be executing the 'get code' again? Assuming that's expensive to do, then the preference would be to do that once per instance and then reuse that result later, if that makes sense?

Comment: If i understand, you want to do a mix between "use singleton / get multiple instance". If you're saying that you want to save the instance when we do the first `get`, you can do it by saving your instances into an array for example, and reuse it later, but it is not a really good solution. If you do this, it tends to be the Singletons pattern, and in agular, Service are already Singleton. 

I thinks to get multiple instance of the same service, this kind of pattern that i've posted is a good solution. You can run into, and make some modification. It depend on you :)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, yeah I had a feeling my use case was probably a little on the unusual side, I'll have a think about it