# Multiple instances of $http in Angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to remove Restangular from project I'm working on as we are not using most of it's features and it just adds to application's weight. I want to go with plain $http instead.

Is it possible to have multiple instances of `$http` service with different configurations? To for example have different interceptors or baseUrl

In Restangular you can do following:

```
app.factory('BingRestangular', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setBaseUrl('http://www.bing.com');
  });
});
```

Then you can just inject `BingRestangular` which will be a preconfigured instance of Restangular.

Is there such thing possible with `$http` or maybe there is some way to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use the Factory pattern in AngularJS. Services are Singletons and cannot have multiple instances. Factories can be used to create multiple instances though.

```
function User(userId, $http) {

    var self = this;    

    $http.get('/api/user/', {userId: userId}).success(function(result) {

        self.details = result.data;
    }):
}

userFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
function userFactory($http) {

    return function(user) {

        return new User(user, $http);
    } 
}
angular.module('app').factory('user', userFactory);
```

Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919062/angularjs-multiple-instances-of-the-same-service)

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question. I'm trying to get multiple instances of $http object so each can be preconfigured. Those instances can be then singletons within angular di.

Comment: You can create a factory that returns a new instance of the `$http` object, and make it available throughout your project. Not sure if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I've found workaround. All interceptors and other stuff can be provided in config of single request. So I've made wrapper on `$http` object (proxy pattern) that provides for example preconfigured interceptors. This way I can have `myHttpA` with one set of interceptors and `myHttpB` with other set of interceptors. I don't use default variables set to `$http` singleton at all.

This is the the best I could come up with, as I couldn't find any way to create multiple instances of $http with different defaults.